# Match values in two cells and return a value in third column

Tags: r

I want to compare two columns, if the values in each cell matches, then create a new cell say it is matching or not. I use `match` function and am getting weird result or I do something wrong

my sample data

```
df <- dput(structure(list(col1 = c("day", "day", "day", "day", "day", 
"day", "day", "night", "night", "day", "day", "day", "day", "day", 
"day", "night", NA, "day", "night", "day"), col2 = c("day", "day", 
"day", "day", "day", "day", "day", "night", "day", "day", "day", 
"day", "day", "day", "day", "night", "day", "day", "day", "day"
)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame"))
```

I want to check if values in `col1` and `col2` are matching

```
tmp$match <- match(tmp$col1, tmp$col2)
```

This is what I get

```
    col1  col2 match
1    day   day     1
2    day   day     1
3    day   day     1
4    day   day     1
5    day   day     1
6    day   day     1
7    day   day     1
8  night night     8
9  night   day     8
10   day   day     1
11   day   day     1
12   day   day     1
13   day   day     1
14   day   day     1
15   day   day     1
16 night night     8
17   NA   day     8
18   day   day     1
19 night   day     8
20   day   day     1
```

As you can see, any row that has two `day` return `1` but two `night` and a `day` and `night` return value 8 (even missing value)

I want to get correct results for a match with different value in `match` column

Comment: What do you expect as your output?

Comment: Are you looking for `tmp$col1 == tmp$col2`?

Comment: It is the expected behavior of `match`.  In your case, both have duplicates and the index returned wil be first index of the second vector i.e. the 8th element in 'col2' is 'night' (first occurence) whereas the 'day' is the first element

Comment: @NelsonGon, if it is a match to get 1, mismatch 0

Comment: If you use `unique`, then you will get 1 and 2, and subtract 1 gets 0 and 1 `match(df$col1, unique(df$col2)) - 1`

Comment: @sindri_baldur, my question is regarding match. I can use this to get correct answer `ifelse(tmp$col1 == tmp$col2, 0, 1)`

Comment: @akrun this will gives 0 and 1 as answer, but the mismatch and match will get the same values. I am not worry if the value is 1 or 8, why mismatch and match get same value?

Comment: It is not an elementwise comparison.  It is giving the index of the element in the second dataset that matches (first match).  For elementwise comparison, use `==` as suggested in the comments.